# Can Google Desktop be used with 12.04?

Tags: google

I would like to use Google Desktop with ubuntu 12.04.  I have seen (old)notices of Google Desktop being discontinued; can this be so?

Answer (score 5):

[Google Desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Desktop) was discontinued [September 2011](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/fall-spring-clean.html), so the correct answer here is '**Google Desktop should no longer be used**'. It is not receiving updates or security patches, so it isn't recommended to use it.

You need to find an alternative like KDE's Plasma widgets or Conky.

Comment: Another nice alternative is Recoll (sudo apt-get install recoll).

Answer (score 2):

As Tom points out, there are security issues but if that's not a problem in your situation you can find the old google-desktop-linux package [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_stable_non_free/stable/non-free/base/google-desktop-linux). It will install on newer versions of Ubuntu.